# How to consume a RSS feed and read the dc:creator element

Tags: asp.net, rss

I am trying to get this to work

I am using [this code](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/retrieving-data-from-an-rss-feed-using-aspnet-web-pages-with-razor-syntax) and it works fine by itself, but now I am trying to get the following element to be read: dc:creator and are not able to.

class file:

```
public class RSSItem

{
    XNamespace dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PubDate { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string strGuid { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Dc_creator { get; set; }


    // Next we’ll modify the constructor. First add a parameter list to the constructor:
    public RSSItem(string title, string description, string link, string guid, 
                   string pubDate, string (dc:creator) //<-- not working but what to use instead)
    {
        // This constructor will be used to parse the RSS xml. Add the following code to the constructor:
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Link = link;
        strGuid = guid;
        PubDate = pubDate; 
        Dc_creator = dc:creator; <-- not working but what to use instead
```

Obviously this does not work:

```
string (dc:creator)) in the constructor
```

page.cshtml:

```
  <div>
     @{
         XNamespace dc = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
         XDocument rss = XDocument.Load("http://rss.xml");
         var items = from elem in rss.Elements("rss").Elements("channel").Elements("item")
        select elem;

         foreach (var item in items)
         { 
             RSSItem rssItem = new RSSItem(
                 item.Element("title").Value,
                 item.Element("link").Value,
                 item.Element("guid").Value,
                 item.Element("description").Value,
                 //item.Element("author").Value,
                 item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                 item.Element(dc + "creator").Value
                 );
           <span class="rssStyle">
              <div>
                 <b>@rssItem.Title</b>
              </div>
    etc etc
```

So how do I manage to have the class constructor read the `dc:creator` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the exact solution, but I had done this using `XmlDocument`. You will have to modify this according to your `RssItem`, I had similar object

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(rss);
//Get Channel Node
XmlNode channelNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel");
if (channelNode != null) {
    //Add NameSpace
    XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("content", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("slash", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");

    //Parse each item
    foreach (XmlNode itemNode in channelNode.SelectNodes("item")) {
        RssFeed rssItem = new RssFeed();
        rssItem.Guid = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("guid").InnerText;
        rssItem.Title = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
        rssItem.CreatedBy = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("dc:creator", nameSpace).InnerText;
        rssItem.Url = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText;
        rssItem.PubDate = DateTime.Parse(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").InnerText);
        rssItem.CommentCount = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("slash:comments", nameSpace).InnerText;
        rssItem.Description = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", nameSpace).InnerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks! I guess this handles the display part, but my problem is more in regards to the constructor inside the class and how to pass the dc:creator thru, since it will not pass with the colon in the variable name.  
  
Meaning this part in the code:  
// Next we’ll modify the constructor. First add a parameter list to the constructor:
    public RSSItem(string title, string description, string link, string guid, 
                   string pubDate, string (dc:creator) //<-- not working but what to use instead)

Comment: You can pass `creator` as normal string and inside constructor you can simply do `Dc_creator = string.Format("dc:{0}",creator);` Let me know if this works.

Comment: Simply amazing! Yep! That did it!
What a pro you are!
Thanks! Now I have learned something new again!